# reference two different version of the same assembly in LINQPad

Tags: c#, namespaces, .net-assembly, linqpad

How can I reference two different version of the same assembly in LINQPad ? On a standard C# application I'd rely on assembly alias, but AFAIK on LINQPad, it's not possible.

Do you know any other dirty way to do it ? 
Of course, I can't recompile the assembly and change their namespace!

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do not just run 2 LinqPads ?

Comment: because I need the two assemblies in the same process. Basically I use LINQPad to query through nHibernate my DataModel, and I need to move data from an instance (with an old schema/model) to the new one, and I'm interested to know if this is possible from LINQPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. In fact, LINQPad tries very hard to stop this happening, because referencing different versions (or copies) of the same assembly is something that nearly always happens by accident. It plays havoc with type resolution (because identical types are incompatible if they come from different assemblies).

Comment: Yes, I agree that it usually  happens by accident, howver .NET do allows to load two different assemblies (from two different locations/contexts) and is something I occasionally use with my datamodels. Nevertheless, unfortunately for me your post answer the question. I'll go back to a standard app and VisualStudio. Thanks.